# Get last created object for each user?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection, say, "Things":

```
{ id: 1
    creator: 1
    created: Today }
{ id: 2
    creator: 2
    created: Today }
{ id: 3
    creator: 2
    created: Yesterday }
```

I'd like to create a query that'll return each Thing created by a set of users, but only their most recently created thing.

What would this look like? I can get search my collection with an array of creators and it works just fine - how can I also only get the most recently created object per user?

```
Thing.find({ _creator : { "$in" : creatorArray })...
```

Comment: What is the type of `created` ?  Is it  `ISODate`?

Comment: Yep, it is an ISODate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot `find`, `sort` and pick the most recent in just a single `find()` query. But you can do it using aggregation:

- `Match` all the records where the creator is amongst the one who we are looking
  for.
- `Sort` the records in descending order based on the created field.
- `Group` the documents based on the creator.
- Pick each creator's first document from the group, which will also be
  his latest.
- `Project` the required fields.

snippet:

```
Thing.aggregate([
{$match:{"creator":{$in:[1,2]}}},
{$sort:{"created":-1}},
{$group:{"_id":"$creator","record":{$first:"$$ROOT"}}},
{$project:{"_id":0,
           "id":"$record.id",
           "creator":"$record.creator",
           "created":"$record.created"}}
], function(err,data){
   })
```

Comment: It is mongoose, the square brackets are optional. - http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.aggregate.

Comment: Beautiful! do you know off hand if I could populate fields in the same command using `.populate`? I'd like to populate the creator field with their username.

Comment: Can you please post a different question, with your actual document. I guess it has embedded references. Answering here would deviate from an answer to the original question.

Comment: Hi @opticon if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: Hey @BatScream, this query takes an insanely long time to run given that the collection only contains about 5 documents. Any advice?

Comment: @opticon - Try removing the `$project` stage and see if there is an performance increase. Index the `creator` field.